# How do you Print in WPF (VB)

Tags: wpf, printing

I have a WPF form that has a toolbar then a StackPanel under it with several controls inside of the StackPanel. One of the buttons on the toolbar is to print. I need to know how to print in a WPF, and more specifically how to print just what is inside of the stackpanel. I am using Visual Basic.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would do

```
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
if (dialog.ShowModel() == true)
{
    dialog.PrintVisual(myStackPanel);
}
```

Sorry for the C#, I don't know VB.NET but the idea is to use the [PrintDialog.PrintVisual()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printvisual.aspx) method

Comment: Someone who can translate to VB.NET feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks. The actual printing job worked, but the margins when it printed were quite a bit off. What I am printing is just text.

Comment: I know some of C#, so I was just fine. Thanks though

Answer (score 3):

Use a [PrintDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.aspx).

```
Using dialog As New PrintDialog
    If dialog.ShowModal() Then dialog.PrintVisual(stackPanel)
End Using
```